# remove substring from string in python

Tags: python, string

I am a beginner in python and I have a string like :

```
comment = "user1@gmail.com : Very bad"
```

What I want is to remove the email and the ":" from the string  and store the rest of the text in another string `(ex. remove "user1@gmail.com :" stored_string = "Very bad " )`

However I am a beginner and I am not well experienced in the python syntax . I would appreciate your help with this small task . Thank you in advance.

Comment: `comment.split(':')[1]` -> ' Very bad' (in "Very bad " you moved the space at the end rather than the beginning)

Comment: Why downvote ? I was clear with my question

Comment: I am not one of the downvoters, perhaps some guys supposed you did not search enough before to ask because you do not even put a proposal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want one of these solutions:

```py
comment = "user1@gmail.com : Very bad"

# Will consume the leading space in " Very bad " as indicated in your
# example.  The argument of 1 limits the number of splits, since it's
# not clear whether ": " can occur in the comment following the email
# address.
stored_string = comment.split(": ", 1)[1]

# The keeps the space in front of "Very bad".
stored_string = comment.split(":", 1)[1]
# If you really don't want the white space, it may be better to strip
# it off the front and back entirely.
stored_string = comment.split(":", 1)[1].strip()

# You could also do this via indexing (though I think it's less clear)
stored_string = comment[comment.index(": ")+2:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the string at `:` and only use the "right"/"last" part:

```
comment.split(":")[-1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
comment = comment.split(":")
stored_string = comment[-1]
print("stored_string: " + stored_string)
```